# Menu hover effect to light out entire rest page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Kindly let me know how can i make menu hover effect like following website:

https://www.bankalhabib.com/

```
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>Contact</li>
<li>Num</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You really need to spend more time writing out your question and provide a sample html with css.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you Use `addClass()` and CSS:

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

This requires that you add CSS rules to style the opacity:

```
ul:hover li {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

ul li.hovered {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/49Qvm/2/).

Incidentally, if you could show some *effort* that you may have put into solving your own question, you may not get quite so many down-votes. It really does read as a demand, rather than a question as currently written.

You could, of course, use simple CSS:

```
ul:hover li {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

ul li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/49Qvm/1/).

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, sorry for not questioning in detail, i edited your fiddle just one issue how can i dim the rest of the page currently only menu options are getting dim http://jsfiddle.net/49Qvm/4/

Answer (score 0):

**The Overlay Effect**

On the site of interest (https://www.bankalhabib.com/), the page dims/darkens when you mouse over the navigation links, "Home" for example.

This effect is the result of the following element:

```
<span class="overlay" style="height: 2464px; display: none;"></span>
```

which is hidden (`display: none`) by default.

This element is made visible by the following jQuery action (found in: js/custom_js.js):

```
/*Over Lay Display controll in bottom*/
$(document).ready(function() {
$(" ul.mainNav li.home").mouseover(function() {
$(".overlay").css({'display':'block'});
$(" ul.mainNav").css({'z-index':'8'});
$(" .dropDown").css({'z-index':'8'});
})
});
```

The trick is fairly simple, two steps.

(1) Display the `overlay` element

(2) Change the `z-index` of the navigation element and the dropDown class so that the menu is visible above the overlay.

The overlay is closer to the view (z-index is higher) than the rest of the website so its background color masks/dims the rest of the website, except for the navigation elements that were shifted up the z-axis.

Now that you know what to look for, you can study the CSS and jQuery details to learn how to implement it in another situation.

Comment: You are asking for a lot of free work... anyone for a bounty? Try up voting my answer before asking for more work.

Comment: I cannot offer any bounty all i got is 14 REP :(, can i give you my 14 rep points?

Comment: I am hoping someone else will see this...

Comment: still thanks for taking your time to look into my issue :)

Comment: I worked on this a bit but the jQuery is a bit tricky and I don't really have time to sort it all out and write production quality code pro-bono. Good luck.